# ASP.NET Core Shared Cookie Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

I have read the MS instructions and several threads here on SO.... and I am out of ideas. I have 2 .net core 3.0 web applications. I use Okta for identity management and want to be able to SSO between my apps - which all works just fine locally.

However, when I deploy it to my development environment in Azure, it doesn't work because the cookies written by site 1 can't be read by site 2. I thought, oh, of course, the solution is to just fix the cookie domain. But that didn't work either.

So here is where I am at:

Site one: dev-app.mysite.com
Site two: dev.mysite.com

If I don't explicitly set the cookie domain, site 1 will write the cookie with dev-app.mysite.com as the cookie.

If I *do* explicitly set the cookie domain to ".mysite.com" (per the documentaiton), then I have an even bigger problem - which is that site 1 can't see it at all!

Here is the relevant code (same in both apps)

```
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });
```

and where I setup the authentication cookie:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn");
                options.Cookie.Name = cookieName;
                options.Cookie.Domain = cookieDomain;
            })
            .AddOktaMvc(oktaMvcOptions);
```

Note I already have taken care of the cookie application name, the shared data protection keys, etc. The only thing that is holding this up is whatever the domain problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the strangest thing I have ever seen. I have found that if I do this, it works:

```
options.Cookie.Domain = "mydomain.com";
```

However, if I put that very same value into appSettings.json and read it from there. The same *exact* value, it doesn't work.

I debugged it locally and discovered that somehow my variable:

```
                var cookieName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SharedCookies:CookieName");
```

which is declared right before the call here, goes out of scope where I am using it.... even though a variable I declared right next to it is totally fine. I have no clue how this is even possible, so I thought I'd try moving the declarations:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                var cookieDomain = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SharedCookies:CookieDomain");
                var cookieName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SharedCookies:CookieName");

                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn");
                options.Cookie.Name = cookieName;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.Domain = cookieDomain;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            })
            .AddOktaMvc(oktaMvcOptions);
```

And... nope, still does not work. The only way I can get it to work is to actually type the domain in directly. If I step through the code line by line I am setting it to the same exact value as that of the variable. This is so bizarre.

If anyone has any ideas on how this is possible, please let me know.